# Facebook release has key make erroe for android studio development

Tags: android, facebook, sha1

In android studio when i release a build through

menu -> Build -> generate signed APK

Apk is prepared. now i have generate

keytool -exportcert -alias MeasurePal -keystore E:\Key\MeasurePal.jks | C:\OPENSSL\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\OPENSSL\bin\openssl.exe base64

got a key: iHI806h/qu6wABNnAzlyRiuPhf4=

but it not grand access from Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collect new open ssl from

https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads

and then do like

```
C:\openssl\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias aliasName -keystore "C:\Users\s\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64
Enter keystore password:  android
```